# Jquery Smart Usage for changing Images on Ids

Tags: jquery, html, image, css, hover

HTML Section

```
 <div class="features-sect">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="feat-heading text-center">
    <h3>Features</h3>
    </div>
    <!--feat-heading-->

    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="tabs">
    <div class="icon-text-blk text-center"> <a onmouseover="imgChange1()" href="#" class="icon-1">
        <div class="icon-cont icon-01" ></div>
        </a>
        <div class="text-cont text-center">
        <h5>Manage Registrations</h5>
        <p>Check attendee list and ticket sales revenue upfront in your dashboard. Offer Discounts and more.</p>
        </div>
        <!--text-cont--> 

    </div>
    <!--icon-text-blk-->

    <div class="icon-text-blk text-center"> <a onmouseover="imgChange2()"  href="#" class="icon-2" >
        <div class="icon-cont icon-02"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="text-cont text-center">
        <h5>Manage Registrations</h5>
        <p>Check attendee list and ticket sales revenue upfront in your dashboard. Offer Discounts and more.</p>
        </div>
        <!--text-cont--> 

    </div>
    <!--icon-text-blk-->

    <div class="icon-text-blk text-center"> <a onmouseover="imgChange3()" href="#" class="icon-3" >
        <div class="icon-cont icon-03" id="3"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="text-cont text-center">
        <h5>Manage Registrations</h5>
        <p>Check attendee list and ticket sales revenue upfront in your dashboard. Offer Discounts and more.</p>
        </div>
        <!--text-cont--> 

    </div>
    <!--icon-text-blk--> 

    </div>
    <!--tabs--> 

    </div>
    <!--col-md-3-->

    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <div class="image-tabs">
    <div class="icon-01-img tab_content" id="tab1"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/smart-registration-management.png" width="555" height="450" /> </div>
    <!--icon-01-img-->

    <div class="icon-02-img tab_content" id="tab2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/custom-registration.png" width="555" height="450" /> </div>
    <!--icon-01-img-->

    <div class="icon-03-img tab_content" id="tab3"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ticket-sale-widget.png" width="555" height="450" /> </div>
    <!--icon-01-img-->

    <div class="icon-04-img tab_content" id="tab4"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/fastest-money-clearance.png" width="555" height="450" /> </div>
    <!--icon-01-img-->

    <div class="icon-05-img tab_content" id="tab5"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/customer-service.png" width="555" height="450" /> </div>
    <!--icon-01-img-->

    <div class="icon-06-img tab_content" id="tab6"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/engage-your-attendees.png" width="555" height="450" /> </div>
    <!--icon-01-img--> 

    </div>
    <!--image-tabs--> 
    </div>
    <!--col-md-6-->

    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="icon-text-blk text-center"> <a onmouseover="imgChange4()" href="#" class="icon-4">
    <div class="icon-cont icon-04" ></div>
    </a>
    <div class="text-cont text-center">
        <h5>Manage Registrations</h5>
        <p>Check attendee list and ticket sales revenue upfront in your dashboard. Offer Discounts and more.</p>
    </div>
    <!--text-cont--> 

    </div>
    <!--icon-text-blk-->

    <div class="icon-text-blk text-center"> <a onmouseover="imgChange5()"  href="#" class="icon-5">
    <div class="icon-cont icon-05"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="text-cont text-center">
        <h5>Manage Registrations</h5>
        <p>Check attendee list and ticket sales revenue upfront in your dashboard. Offer Discounts and more.</p>
    </div>
    <!--text-cont--> 

    </div>
    <!--icon-text-blk-->

    <div class="icon-text-blk text-center"> <a onmouseover="imgChange6()"  href="#" class="icon-6">
    <div class="icon-cont icon-06" ></div>
    </a>
    <div class="text-cont text-center">
        <h5>Manage Registrations</h5>
        <p>Check attendee list and ticket sales revenue upfront in your dashboard. Offer Discounts and more.</p>
    </div>
    <!--text-cont--> 

    </div>
    <!--icon-text-blk--> 

    </div>
    <!--col-md-3--> 

    </div>
    <!--row--> 
</div>
<!--container--> 
</div>
```

CSS Section

```
.features-sect{width:100%; float:left; padding:80px 0;}
.feat-heading h3{ color:#683594; font-size:32px; padding-bottom:25px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:600; }
.icon-text-blk{width:100%; display:inline-block; margin-bottom:25px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}

.text-cont h5{ color:#000; font-size:18px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:600;}
.text-cont p{ color:#333; font-size:16px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:lighter;}

.icon-cont{width:60px; height:60px; border-radius:100%;  position:relative;}
.icon-01{background:url(../images/icon-1.png) no-repeat center; display:inline-block;}
.icon-02{background:url(../images/icon-2.png) no-repeat center; display:inline-block;}
.icon-03{background:url(../images/icon-3.png) no-repeat center; display:inline-block;}
.icon-04{background:url(../images/icon-4.png) no-repeat center; display:inline-block;}
.icon-05{background:url(../images/icon-5.png) no-repeat center; display:inline-block;}
.icon-06{background:url(../images/icon-6.png) no-repeat center; display:inline-block;}   

a.icon-1:hover .icon-01{background:url(../images/icon-1-hover.png) no-repeat center;}
a.icon-2:hover .icon-02{background:url(../images/icon-2-hover.png) no-repeat center;}
a.icon-3:hover .icon-03{background:url(../images/icon-3-hover.png) no-repeat center;}
a.icon-4:hover .icon-04{background:url(../images/icon-4-hover.png) no-repeat center;}
a.icon-5:hover .icon-05{background:url(../images/icon-5-hover.png) no-repeat center;}
a.icon-6:hover .icon-06{background:url(../images/icon-6-hover.png) no-repeat center;}    

.image-tabs{width:100%; display:inline-block; padding:55px 0;}    

#tab2{display:none;}
#tab3{display:none;}
#tab4{display:none;}
#tab5{display:none;}
#tab6{display:none;}
```

JS Section -> This is the Javascript section

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function imgChange1(){
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById("tab4").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab5").style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById("tab6").style.display = "none"; 
    }
//These are the functions by which one image is displayed in the center and all others are not displayed as their display is none there.

    function imgChange2(){
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab4").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab5").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab6").style.display = "none";
    }
//Like here by hovering on icon 2, image related to icon 2 is only displayed and all others are hidden
    function imgChange3(){
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tab4").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab5").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab6").style.display = "none";

    }
//These are the functions by which one image is displayed in the center and all others are not displayed as their display is none there.    

    function imgChange4(){
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab4").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tab5").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab6").style.display = "none";
    }
//These are the functions by which one image is displayed in the center and all others are not displayed as their display is none there.    

    function imgChange5(){
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab4").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab5").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tab6").style.display = "none";
    }
//These are the functions by which one image is displayed in the center and all others are not displayed as their display is none there.

    function imgChange6(){
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab4").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab5").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tab6").style.display = "block";
    }

//These are the functions by which one image is displayed in the center and all others are not displayed as their display is none there.    

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Fixed code formatting

Answer (score 0):

A smart way for changing images on ID is:

1. change the in line code in this way:

   ```
   <div class="icon-text-blk text-center"><a onmouseover="imgChange('tab1')" href="#" class="icon-1">
   ```

Now you have a new function with a parameter: the element id.

2. Remove all your functions: imgChange1, imgChange2... And write only one function:

   ```
   function imgChange(elementId) {

       [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="tab"]'), function (element, index) {
           if (element.id == elementId) {
               element.style.display = "block";
           } else {
               element.style.display = "none";
           }
       });
   }
   ```